# Identifying source of martian packets

Tags: linux, networking

On a server hosting multiple linux-vservers, I martian packets reported in syslog:

```
[2164343.839846] martian source 10.12.12.2 from MY.PUB.LIC.IP, on dev eth0
[2164343.839850] ll header: e8:40:f2:0a:e9:4e:6c:9c:ed:bb:bd:80:08:00
```

where

- 10.12.12.2 is the IP of a vserver, natted
- MY.PUB.LIC.IP is the ip of eth0, the only physical interface
- e8:40:f2:0a:e9:4e is the mac address of eth0
- 6c:9c:ed:bb:bd:80 is (apparently) the MAC address of an equipment at the data center where the server is

A tcpdump on eth0 show no packet captured, even with rp_filter set to 0 for eth0

```
tcpdump -i eth0 host 10.12.12.2
```

How can I gather more info to identify the problem? Can I dump somehow the packets?

Comment: Have you discussed this with the network administrator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was due to a missing alias on the ethernet interface